# React to a change of the block alignment

Tags: block-editor

So, I have a Gutenberg block that has a custom component inside, that needs to be refreshed if the dimensions of the block change. However, apparently there's no way for me to detect when the `alignment` attribute (`wide` or `full`) has changed.

Is there a way to listen to changes on that attribute, and run a custom callback, when needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that if one uses `wp.data.subscribe`, you're able to intercept any change that occurr in the editor. As you can imagine, this is not very performant. So I've decided to create an extra hidden attribute that stores the old alignment value for the block, and fire the callback only when that attribute and the `align` one are not the same.